# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not working in an universal app

Tags: iphone

I have written an universal application and i have returned YES in the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method. The method is getting called but whenever I change the orientation of Iphone or Ipad the view does not rotate. I have even set the autoresizesSubviews

Comment: What type of Application are you using ? Is it Tabbar or Navigationbased ? You specify returned YES in all of your viewcontrollers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mainly due because some other innerview does not allow/set the orientation change. To make things clear, when you rotate the device, the method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` will be called for every viewcontroller that hangs on your view tree. If any of them returns NO, the interface won't change.

For example, if you have a tabbarcontroller with viewcontrollers A, B, C and D, the method will be called for all of them, doesn't matter if it is being shown right now.

So be sure that you have changed it in all views.

Comment: thanks...... I also found another solution to the problem i.e by subclassing the UITabBarController.